# How to download a file from a url when a button is clicked in angular5 / 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I have a url for ex: abc.net/files/test.ino 
The requirement is to download an .INO file through a button click event in angular 5 or 6

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you can create an anchor tag to download the file on button click event

```
downloadMyFile(){
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'abc.net/files/test.ino');
    link.setAttribute('download', `products.csv`);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
}
```

now call this function from your button

```
<button (click)="downloadMyFile()">download File<button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hussain. Works fine !!

Comment: this function opening a new window, but i wanna download the file without new window

Comment: @AnandanK you can use target _self instead of _blank

Comment: how do you unit test everything between the first and the last line? let's say that whatever attribute was set. Why not have a hidden anchor in the markup, have binding on the attribute values and trigger its click dynamically?

Comment: You can remove the line 'link.setAttribute('download', `products.csv`);', I removed it and it still works without this line.

Answer (score 7):

Adding on to Hussains answer but just doing it with Renderer2 since its not advised to use document directly.

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core'
export class SomeComponent {
   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
   
   downloadFile() {
      const link = this.renderer.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      link.setAttribute('href', 'abc.net/files/test.ino');
      link.setAttribute('download', `products.csv`);
      link.click();
      link.remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: Renderer2 worked perfectly! I think this solution is better than directly working with dom to avoid any compatibility issues across browsers

Comment: You can remove the line 'link.setAttribute('download', `products.csv`);', I removed it and it still works without this line.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the button look like an anchor element through html, for instance:

```
<a href="abc.net/files/test.ino">download</a>
```

You can also try and create a dynamic anchor element:

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
link.href = 'abc.net/files/test.ino';
link.download = path;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @AGR. This works fine. If possible kindly provide angular level solution also for knowledge purpose (let's say calling the url through the http module)
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you need direct download without opening the file then you have to set settings in chrome/opera if you are used these browsers,

**Setting** -> **Advanced** -> **Privacy & security** -> **Content setting** -> **PDF Documents**,
You see "Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome" **Enable** it.

After that put below code in your HTML file,

```
<a [href]="fileURL" target="_blank" class="btn btn-border" download="fileName.pdf">Download</a>
```