# How can I download a file from Firebase Storage to the user PC file system in this Angular application?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on an Angular application using Firebase Storage and I have the following problem.
I correctly uploaded some files into Firebase Storage service.
Now in my application I need to add the possibility to download a specific file into my filesystem.

In my application I have something like this:

[image]

In the previous printscreen you can see a file retrieved from Firebase storage with its preview shown into a table column. The last table column contain the highlighted icon that have to be used to dowlonad the file into the user filesystem.

In my HTML code this is the download button:

```
<button pButton 
        type="button" 
        class="p-button-secondary centered-icon" 
        icon="pi pi-download"
        (click)="downloadAttachment(file)">
</button>
```

This button call the **downloadAttachment()** method of the component TypeScript code passing the to it the **file** object. This object contains some info including the file URL relatedo to Firebase Storage.

So this is my **downloadAttachment()** method:

```
async downloadAttachment(file) {
    console.log("downloadAttachment START");
    console.log("FILE: ", file);

    let fileRef = await this.assetService.downloadAttachment(file.info.file_url);
```

}

This method have to be used to download on the user PC the file related to the **file.info.file_url** URL (this is the Firebase Storage download URL).

But now I have no idea about what I have to do to perform the download.

At the moment the previous code is calling another **downloadAttachment()** service method defined into a service class that simply return the **AngularFireStorageReference** reference of this file

This is the service method:

```
  public async downloadAttachment(attachmentURL) {
    console.log("downloadAttachment() START !!!! attachmentId: " + attachmentURL);

    let httpsReference = this.storage.refFromURL(attachmentURL);
    return httpsReference;
  }
```

But I am not sure that this is a good idea.

So starting from the Firebase Storage download URL represented by the **file.info.file_url** property what can I do to download the file in the user PC filesystem?

Comment: Does that answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587921/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-angular5-6

Comment: @RenaudTarnec it helped but in this way I can open the file into another browser tab...Is it possibile in some way implement the classic download behavior in order to choose where (in what folder on the local filesystem) download the file?